# Set firebase storage to write only

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I need to set firebase storage rules so unauthenticated users can upload a file but can't read a file.

So far I have:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if true
      allow read: if false
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule will help you to read only if user is authenticated else it won't allow. For more details you can read [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics?authuser=0#all_authenticated_users)

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume writing `allow read: if false;`  denies all read access entirely